# Same random guarantee

Tags: java, random

I have got this code:

```
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(64, new Random());
Long longValue=-Math.abs(bigInteger.longValue());
int desiredLen=384;
Random random=new Random(longValue);
byte [] randomString=new byte[desiredLen];
for(int i=0;i<desiredLen;i++)
    randomString[i]=(byte)(Math.abs(random.nextInt())&255);
```

Now there are these values:

- longValue - is sent to other side (server) and later used to generate key again on other side
- randomString - is encryption key generated randomly based on longValue

Simply, client sends message containing first 8 bytes longValue and other stuff is encrypted content by randomString.

What is the guarantee that exactly the same numbers will be generated on all physical and virtual machines and across all Java versions based on received longValue? And how about if client is written in other language like C#?

Comment: You can shorten your code considerably by using the [Random.nextLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextLong--) and [Random.nextBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBytes-byte:A-) methods.

Comment: You absolutely should not use `Random` for secure encryption. It's trivial to reverse. You will want to use a stream cipher, e.g. chacha20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API documentation of [`java.util.Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) specifies the exact algorithm being used.

This isn't a cast-iron guarantee that things won't change, not as much as the signatures of methods, but any implementation detail you publish in an API doc is almost as binding. Certainly Oracle are highly unlikely to ever change it.

Whether you feel that's enough for you is up to you.

*I personally wouldn't rely on it, not because it might change but because it introduces a dependency that may not be immediately obvious.
The decision should also depend on how important the task is. If it's a hobby project, it could be okay, if it's bank-to-bank communication, I wouldn't even think about using `Random` at all, as it isn't cryptographically secure.*

As for interoperability with other languages, there's no guarantee whatsoever.

Comment: The documentation absolutely is a cast-iron guarantee.  That's the fundamental basis of object-oriented design:  the documentation is a *contract,* not just "here's a description of what I wrote."

Comment: @VGR It isn't guaranteed that it won't change in the future. I clarified that. Or at least it's not as strong a guarantee as say compilation compatibility.

Comment: As a matter of fact, it is guaranteed that it will not change in the future.  That too is a fundamental concept of OO:  A contract is a permanent guarantee.  If Java ever wants a different random number generation algorithm, it will introduce a new class.  That's why, for example, the StringBuilder class was introduced in 1.5 rather than altering the existing behavior of StringBuffer.

Comment: @VGR I disagree with you saying that change is guaranteed. The only way to guarantee uniqueness is by keeping track of them in a database and comparing a new random with all the previously generated randoms. Neither `Random` or `SecureRandom` guarantee uniqueness of generated numbers.

Comment: @DrZoo I don't think that's the issue here, the question is whether two `Random` instances on two different versions of Java would return the same number sequence, given an identical seed. And they would.

Comment: @biziclop you were much better at putting it into words than I was haha. I also agree with your statement.

Comment: so I better implement my own Random that I can reimplement in other languages